# Teste de desempenho, como reduzir o tempo de execução

Tags: python

Quero criar uma função que retorne uma lista com todas as potências de 2 dos números de 0 a 99, no menor tempo possível.

Até o momento realizei 3 testes e meu script atual é esse:

```
import timeit
import math

lista = [x for x in range(100)]

def powf(x):
    return math.pow(x,2)

def teste1():
    x = list(map(powf, lista))
    return x

def teste2(x):
    x = [powf(x) for x in lista]
    return x    

def teste3(y):
    listareturn = []
    for i in y:
        listareturn.append(powf(i))
    return listareturn

print('teste1')
print(timeit.timeit("teste1()", setup="from __main__ import teste1, lista", number=100000))
print('teste2')
print(timeit.timeit("teste2(lista)", setup="from __main__ import teste2, lista", number=100000))
print('teste3')
print(timeit.timeit("teste3(lista)", setup="from __main__ import teste3, lista", number=100000))
```

output:

```
teste1 = 3.0448245999999997
teste2 = 3.2884434
teste3 = 3.5317369999999997
```

Seria importante para mim descobrir maneiras mais performáticas de escrever em python.

É possível reduzir ainda mais o tempo de execução dessa função ?

Comment: numpy é muito bom para calculo em listas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma mais rápida é aquela que você empurra a complexidade de construir a lista para o compilador ou para a inicialização do programa de forma que ela só precise ser construída uma vez.

Veja isso:

```
import timeit
import math

lista = [x for x in range(100)]

def powf(x):
    return math.pow(x,2)

def teste1():
    x = list(map(powf, lista))
    return x

def teste2(x):
    x = [math.pow(x, 2) for x in lista]
    return x    

def teste3(y):
    listareturn = []
    for i in y:
        listareturn.append(powf(i))
    return listareturn

potencias = tuple(2**x for x in range(100))

def teste4():
    return potencias

print('teste1')
print(timeit.timeit("teste1()", setup="from __main__ import teste1, lista", number=100000))
print('teste2')
print(timeit.timeit("teste2(lista)", setup="from __main__ import teste2, lista", number=100000))
print('teste3')
print(timeit.timeit("teste3(lista)", setup="from __main__ import teste3, lista", number=100000))
print('teste4')
print(timeit.timeit("teste4()", setup="from __main__ import teste4, lista", number=100000))
print('indexando')
print(teste4()[50])
```

A saída na minha máquina foi essa:

```
teste1
12.5717021
teste2
7.806296900000001
teste3
11.117290700000002
teste4
0.019261000000000195
indexando
1125899906842624
```

Observe que a forma 4 é muuuuuito mais rápida que as demais, afinal, a única coisa que ela faz é um `return` de uma tupla fixa.

Comment: Vitor mas como eu conseguiria visualizar e manipular esse objeto posteriormente, já que está sendo retornado um <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000014B02D54E48> ?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Daí depende o que você quer fazer com ele depois. Qualquer medição de desempenho só é válida se for considerada o contexto no qual aquilo que é medido será utilizado, pois certas otimizações podem ou não ser válidas nesse contexto. Você não explicou na sua pergunta qual é o contexto no qual você quer usar essa lista.

Comment: Eu não posso refutar isso, você tem razão. Mas existe uma forma de acessar o resultado do Index 50 com esse método ?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Editei o código e refiz o teste para ser possível indexar e demonstrar como fazer.

Comment: Victor ficou muito mais rápido e 100% funcional para o que eu estava precisando. Por favor você pode editar sua resposta e alterar a formula da variável potencias para x**2, e também verificar o tempo que você colocou no ultimo teste pq aqui na minha maquina eu consegui em 0.00858150000000002 muito menor que os outros já na sua resposta aparentemente esse foi o procedimento mais lento.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves O `0.019261000000000195` é o tempo do `teste4`, muito rápido que todos os outros. Já o `1125899906842624` é só o resultado de usar `print(teste4()[50])`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, em relação a redução de tempo tente usar:

```
from collections import deque

lista =deque([x for x in range(100)])
```

Consegui uma leve redução no tempo de execução.

Aqui  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque você encontra mais informações sobre a lib collections.